# Matrix decomposition equality

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

If a matrix $\bf X = UV'$ such that $\bf UU' = \Sigma$, $\bf{VV'} = I$, $\bf V\Sigma = X'XV$ and $\bf U = XV$ where $\bf \Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

From the equality $\bf V\Sigma = X'XV$, we can deduce that columns of $\bf V$ is the eigenvectors of the matrix $\bf X'X$. Similarly, we can deduce that $\bf \Sigma U = XX'U$, which makes $\bf U$ the eigenvectors of $\bf XX'$.  But I am told that $\bf U$ is the eigenvectors of $\bf XX'$ scaled by the eigen values of $\bf XX'$. Where I am wrong ?

Comment: Is $V$ a square matrix? And how did you deduce $U\Sigma=XX'U$?

Comment: $\bf U\Sigma = XX'U$ implies $\bf V\Sigma = X'XV$ if $\bf U = XV$. How do you show the other way? Namely given $\bf V\Sigma = X'XV$ and $\bf U = XV$ how do you get $\bf U\Sigma = XX'U$?

Comment: There was a minor error in the OP.  I made use of the fact that $\bf UU' = XVU'$ to deduce that columns of $\bf U$ are eigen vectors os $\bf XX'$